# Does rviz support a viewpoint that follows the robot?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on a robot that will be performing long out-and-back traverses. I'd like to use rviz to show the local sensor data we're collecting, but I'm stuck trying to figure out how to get the viewpoint to follow the robot.

If I select the fixed frame to be a constant offset from the robot, then all the LaserScans fall right on top of each other. If I set the fixed frame to be a world frame, then the sensor data looks great, but the robot quickly drives off the screen.

So, is there a way to control where the map is centered independent of which transformation is being used to display the data?

(I'm using Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214373/does-rviz-support-a-viewpoint-that-follows-the-robot?/) by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1780 on 2015-07-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this pull request will be what you want:

https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/pull/861

It hasn't been merged and released yet, but it's on my todo list. It will probably not be released into Hydro though. It should be in the Indigo and Jade versions of rviz. If you're set on using Hydro they you'll want to apply that pull requests patch to the hydro-devel branch of rviz and build it from source.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3